# can google find my page if the meta tags are not constant?

Tags: seo

I have only one page on my site called index.php and this page has its content and meta tags (like keywords and description) stored in mysql so that if you visit my site like 
`www.mysite.com/xxxxx` 
then index.php get the meta tags and body content from mysql that belong to page xxxxx.

My question is does google find these pages?
Does google search inside mysql?

Comment: No he doesnt search inside mysql, but he will visit your webpage links, and read updated metatags and body content :)

Answer (score 1):

Search engines see the final HTML your code produces. If your code produces HTML output with different meta content for each page then that is what they will see.

FYI, meta tags do not affect rankings anymore and have not for a very long time. The meta description tag *may* be used in the search results description for a page but it won't affect the ranking of that page.

Comment: oh thats interesting, so what does the rankings depend on?

Comment: Hundreds of other factors

Comment: say someone searched for the word "hello" on google and say I have a page stored on mysql belonging to the word hello but the only way to get there is to go to www.mysite.com/hello so that the index .php can echo the result from mysql on itself, will google find this page?

Comment: Google will find any page you can find normally. There is nothing special about google. They are just a regular user.